# What are most common Wall Street explanations for why IPOs are underpriced on average?

Tags: banking

It is now well documented that stock prices, on average, rise on the IPO date. This implies that the IPO prices were systematically "set too low" on average.

Why is this the case, according to Wall Street people? I know there are various asymmetry information-based stories told by academics, but I'm curious what Wall Street people think.

I'm aware of the story that issuers like to "see their prices pop". I don't think this explains the whole phenomenon, and at a minimum, this does not explain the variation in the degree of underpricing across IPOs.

Comment: I think it is also linked to the way underwriters are compensated

Comment: @Mayeulsgc Can you expand on that?